# Rook polynomial for a board with more allowed positions than forbidden

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I have a 4x6 chessboard. Since the original problem seems too complicated I tried to convert it to a set of easier problems. The black spots indicate forbidden positions. What I tried was calculating the polynom for completely empty chessboard (eg. all positions are allowed) which is:

> $1 + 24x + 180x^2 + 480x^3 + 360x^4$

Then I inverted the original problem to have less available positions and did the calculation which is:

> $1 + 7x + 13x^2 + 8x^3 + x^4$

And then I tried to simply substract the inverted result from the overall result.

> $(1 + 24x + 180x^2 + 480x^3 + 360x^4) - (1 + 7x + 13x^2 + 8x^3 + x^4) = 17x + 167x^2 + 472x^3 + 359x^4$

But that is obviously wrong, since I lose the first number and some online calculator shows a different result too. I believe I should maybe use principle of inclusion and exclusion but I have no idea why and how.

[image: my solution]

Comment: It is highly recommended that you use MathJax/LaTeX to format your question so that it is readable. There are many tutorials available all over the web. Otherwise, very nice first question, and welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: alright, I fixed that. Hope it is correct now.

Comment: looks much nicer. later today i will look more closely at your problem.

Comment: And what ritual transforms the patterns into polynomials?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of rook polynomials? Because I am not the best person to tell you how it works (I am just studying it). But if you have any knowledge, I am finding how many ways I can put 1, 2, 3, .. ,n chess towers on the field without any of them endangering the others. So for the 1 square there is 1 way to put 0 tower and 1 way to put 1 tower. Therefore 1+(1)x. The other variations are just bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The approach to calculate the rook polynomial $R(x)$ of the forbidden places is fine. Here we have
\begin{align*}
R(x)=1 + 7x + 13x^2 + 8x^3 + x^4
\end{align*}

The following holds: Let $R_{m,n}(x)$, WLOG $m\leq n$ denote the rook polynomial of an $(m\times n)$-rectangle with no forbidden places. Let $B\subseteq [m]\times[n]$ be a set of forbidden places and $R(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}r_kx^k$ be the rook polynomial of $B$. The rook polynomial $Q(x)$ of the *complement* $([m]\times [n])\setminus B$ is
\begin{align*}
Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}r_k(-x)^kR_{m-k,n-k}(x)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The formula (1) is a direct consequence of the inclusion-exclusion principle and can be found e.g. in ch. 7 of *[Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486425363)* by John Riordan.

> We calculate the complementary rook polynomial $Q(x)$ of $R(x)=1 + 7x + 13x^2 + 8x^3 + x^4$ using (1) as
>   \begin{align*}
> Q(x)&=R_{4,6}(x)-7xR_{3,5}(x)+13x^2R_{2,4}(x)\\
> &\qquad-8x^3R_{1,3}(x)+x^4R_{0,2}(x)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The rook polynomial $R_{m,n}(x)$ of an $(m\times n)$-rectangle is given as
\begin{align*}
R_{m,n}(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{m,n\}}\binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{j}j!x^j  \qquad m,n \geq 0\tag{3}
\end{align*}
We calculate the rook polynomials for the rectangles in (2) and obtain
\begin{align*}
R_{4,6}(x)&=1+24+180x^2+480x^3+360x^4\\
R_{3,5}(x)&=1+15x+60x^2+60x^3\\
R_{2,4}(x)&=1+8x+12x^2\\
R_{1,3}(x)&=1+3x\\
R_{0,2}(x)&=1
\end{align*}

> It follows from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{Q(x)}&=1+24+180x^2+480x^3+360x^4\\
> &\qquad-7x\left(1+15x+60x^2+60x^3\right)\\
> &\qquad+13x^2\left(1+8x+12x^2\right)-8x^3\left(1+3x\right)+x^4\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+17x+88x^2+156x^3+73x^4}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We can use result (4), exchange the roles of $R(x)$ and $Q(x)$ and calculate $R(x)$ from $Q(x)$ as cross-check.

We obtain

> \begin{align*}
> &R_{4,6}(x)-17xR_{3,5}(x)+88x^2R_{2,4}(x)-156x^3R_{1,3}(x)\\
> &\qquad\quad+73x^4R_{0,2}(x)\\
> &\quad=1+24+180x^2+480x^3+360x^4\\
> &\quad\qquad-17x\left(1+15x+60x^2+60x^3\right)\\
> &\quad\qquad+88x^2\left(1+8x+12x^2\right)-156x^3\left(1+3x\right)+73x^4\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=1+7x+13x^2+8x^3+x^4}\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=R(x)}
> \end{align*}